# android studio cannot resolve symbol id

Tags: android

I have a problem with this:

```
EditText_Username = (EditText)findViewById(id.EditText_Username);
```

I have an error `cannot resolve symbol id`
Every code line that has id have the same error.
I tried rebuilding the whole project and sync it with gradle but the error remains.
PS: the app was launching normally in the emulator even with the (id) in the code.

Comment: Did you statically import `R.id`? Why?

Comment: The typical problem with this error is a misconfigured  XML file

Comment: Any way to correct the XML file? Do I need to add something in my XML file?

Comment: check your layout there is any error or in res folder at some place configured wrong ..

Comment: You need to fix an import or a syntax error, not necessarily "add" anything. It would help if you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with all the files that you edited between the error and the last working state

Comment: Maybe add some of that xml here? ...  - but please check before, if it is well-formed xml ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
EditText EditText_Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_Username);
```

instead. and verify that you have

```
android:id="@+id/EditText_Username"
```

for the EditText object you're searching by Id in your XML using your Java class.

Answer (score 0):

See your AndroidManifest.xml, you will have a package Id. Now replace id with packageId.R.id in your Java file

Answer (score 0):

What class you are using? Activity or Fragment?

**if Fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    EditText_Username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Username);
    return view;
}
```

and also for a good coding practice, make your object small case like "editTextUsername" "etUsername", "imgThumb", "tvTitle",  etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007 pointed out, you probably [statically imported](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) the R class.

As a solution, place your caret before the `id.EditText_Username` section of your code, then press `Alt+Enter`. In the popup window, choose `Expand static import to R.id`, then choose `Replace all and delete the import`. Now your `import static` statement is deleted, and all occurrences are renamed to `R.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write R.id.

The code is first compiled and then run on a real or virtual device. So it is impossible to compile for an emulator but not a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a variable in the same scope that you may have named R.  If you have such a variable named R, then rename it to something else.